# Why can't SOCKS proxies be used for http?

Tags: firefox, networking, proxy, http-proxy, socks

If I enter a SOCKS proxy into the http section of firefox proxy settings, it doesn't work, only with a http proxy. Shouldn't socks work for this, they're both proxies?